# Berkelium compilation errors

Tags: c++, python, chromium, berkelium

This is a repost of an issue I posted on the berkelium project on github (https://github.com/sirikata/berkelium/issues/19).

My question:

During chromium compilation on Linux (Debian testing, 64bit, gcc 4.7.1, cmake 2.8.9), the python script `action_makenames.py` fails with the following error:

```
...
  ACTION webcore_bindings_sources_HTMLNames out/Release/obj/gen/webkit/HTMLNames.cpp
  ACTION webcore_bindings_sources_SVGNames out/Release/obj/gen/webkit/SVGNames.cpp
  ACTION webcore_bindings_sources_MathMLNames out/Release/obj/gen/webkit/MathMLNames.cpp
  ACTION webcore_bindings_sources_XLinkNames out/Release/obj/gen/webkit/XLinkNames.cpp
  ACTION webcore_bindings_sources_XMLNSNames out/Release/obj/gen/webkit/XMLNSNames.cpp
Unknown parameter math for tags/attrs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 174, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 156, in main
    assert returnCode == 0
AssertionError
make: *** [out/Release/obj/gen/webkit/MathMLNames.cpp] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Unknown parameter a for tags/attrs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 174, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 156, in main
    assert returnCode == 0
AssertionError
Unknown parameter a interfaceName for tags/attrs
make: *** [out/Release/obj/gen/webkit/SVGNames.cpp] Error 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 174, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 156, in main
    assert returnCode == 0
AssertionError
make: *** [out/Release/obj/gen/webkit/HTMLNames.cpp] Error 1
Unknown parameter actuate for tags/attrs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 174, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 156, in main
    assert returnCode == 0
AssertionError
make: *** [out/Release/obj/gen/webkit/XLinkNames.cpp] Error 1
Unknown parameter xmlns for tags/attrs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 174, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "scripts/action_makenames.py", line 156, in main
    assert returnCode == 0
AssertionError
make: *** [out/Release/obj/gen/webkit/XMLNSNames.cpp] Error 1
Failed to install: chromium
```

It looks like the python script is calling a perl script, and the perl script is dying on line 209:

```
die "Unknown parameter $parameter for tags/attrs\n" if !defined($parameters{$parameter});
```

The 'unknown parameter's are:

- math
- a
- a interfaceName
- actuate
- xmlns

I'm not sure where these parameters are coming from.

Anyone have any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out to be a preprocessor bug for gcc 4.6. As a fix, you have to remove the `-P` parameter of the gcc preprocessor command in `make_names.pl`.

**Bug report**:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46411

**Bug fix**:
http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/84123

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you may be missing a directory, a la

http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=45713

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jspcal.  Turns out it was a preprocessor flag for GCC 4.6 that was causing the problem.